# How could I create an iframe page like this in Drupal?

Tags: 7

I want one of my content type pages to look like this http://flippa.com/auctions/2647380/site
The data at the top would be filled by cck fields from that content type. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field for URL, and then in your theme spit out the URL field value as an IFRAME tag.

Comment: How would I style it so that everything is gone from the page except the node and the iframe?